# xlsx file created with Pandas ExcelWriter requires repair

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

As stated in the title, the xlsx created with the code below is corrupt.
Can anyone see a problem in my code?

```
if "O-" in project:
    path = project_folder_order
elif "Q-" in project:
    path = project_folder_quote

book = load_workbook(path)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(str(path), engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
worksheet = writer.sheets["Create"]

worksheet.cell(row=int(no_target_lang_len) + 1, column=1).fill = PatternFill(start_color='FFFF00', end_color='FFFF00', fill_type='solid')                                                                          

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"\\awsdfpudblapp.xxx.de\Planet\Krake\\" + project + "\\4_Term_TO_DO_" + project + ".csv")
df1_create = df1["Create"]
df1_search = df1["Search"]

df1_create.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Create", index=False, startcol=0, startrow=1, merge_cells=True)
df1_search.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Search", index=False, startcol=0, startrow=no_target_lang_len, merge_cells=True)

worksheet.merge_cells(start_row=int(no_target_lang_len) + 1, start_column=1, end_row=int(no_target_lang_len) + 1, end_column=4)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

The Excel error message is rather vague:

error052160_01.xml
Errors were detected in file 'D:\Users\xxx\4_Term_TODO_Q-21-001727-01.xlsx'
Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded.

After letting Excel repair the file, the content does appear, but I need to save it as another version in order to be able to use the file in another application.

I also have the problem with this somewhat shorter code:

```
if "O-" in project:
    path = project_folder_order
elif "Q-" in project:
    path = project_folder_quote

book = load_workbook(path)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')
writer.book = book

df1 = pd.read_csv(r"\\awsdfpudblapp.xxx.de\Planet\Krake\\" + project + "\\4_Term_TO_DO_" + project + ".csv")
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Term candidates", index=False, merge_cells=True)


writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the problem might be without either the error message or the original file?

Comment: Appologies, it was cut off. I do realise the error message is essential.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with shorter code, i.e. does Excel attempt to repair if you use ExcelWriter to create an empty spreadsheet?

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with shorter code, which I will add above. But I can create an empty spreadsheet with ExcelWriter without creating this problem.

Comment: The problem isn't with new workbooks but with existing ones. They can have all kinds of things in them that are difficult to handle and Pandas is completely dependent upon openpyxl for this. Try simply opening and saving the file (with a different name) in openpyxl and open an issue on the openpyxl bug tracker.

Comment: comment out writer.save() and writer.close().  writer is closed when to_excel(writer) is called

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced this problem before.

In your last line of code.
Just change `writer.close()` to `book.close()`. It works fine in my code. May cause from `load_workbook` and you didn't close them.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the last lines of your code :

```
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

Try to use:

```
book.save()
```

**My opinion:** when you are saving the `writer` object it is only some part of excel and it is advised to keep the whole excel file, so the `book` object as an entire excel should save excel without any damage.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick.

Comment: nice to read :) Good luck!